# SQL Server connection issue (error 26)

Tags: .net, sql-server, winforms, exception, ado.net

I've installed a database on an instance of SQL Server Express.  My client application runs and succesfully connects with the database when I run the app from the server machine.  However the application will not connect to the database when I run it on other PCs on the same network.  I keep getting the error message:

> A network-related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server . . . . . error 26 - Error Locating Server / Instance Specified

When I have had this error in the past it was because the SQL Browser service was not running.  However when I look for SQL Browser in services on the server, it simply isn't there.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you specify the instance? Something like `db_servername\instance`

Comment: The app is probably accessing the "local" instance, so when you move it to another machine it won't work.

Comment: Post the connection string here if possible. A firewall could be blocking clients too. Did you try connecting with Management studio or some other database tool to see if you can connect at all?

Comment: It may also be that Sql isn't accepting remote connections - check the surface area configuration and ensure that remote connections are allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the end was to access enable SQL Browser in windows services and ensure that the properties allowed TCP connections on port 134.  Hope that may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

By default the express doesnt advertise sometimes. What did you try connect to?

It should be \SQLEXPRESS